# Moving the middle column to the top on mobile with flex box

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following HTML (simplified):

```
<div class='outer'>
   <div class='nav-prev'></div>
   <div class='content'></div>
   <div class='nav-next'></div>
</div>
```

My current CSS is:

```
.outer {
  display:flex;
}
.content {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

This gives me the three column layout for desktop, with left and right navigation buttons (in the `.nav-prev` and `.nav-next` divs). Something like:

```
< CONTENT >
```

On mobile, however I want the navigation buttons to be below the content (or perhaps above, I haven't decided yet). Something like:

```
CONTENT
 <   >
```

I can't figure out if this is possible with flex. I know I can change `flex-direction:` and reorder the items with `order:`, but I don't think I can put `.nav-prev` and `.nav-next` below `.content` and next to each other without extra container divs that would be incompatible with the desktop 3 column view.

I can obviously have two sets of navigation buttons, shown and hidden as appropriate, but I was wondering if there was a magic flex way to achieve this behavior without doubling up the buttons.

Comment: If you can use `display: grid`. I can show you how to do it.

Comment: I can use `display: grid` if it has the equivalent of `flex-grow` for the content in 3 column mode. I haven't used `display: grid` before. (Or perhaps you are saying switch to grid for mobile?)

Comment: try to use `absolute` position property for navigation button for mobile. like `@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .nav-prev{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
  }
  .nav-next{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
  }
}`

Comment: @jerry - I can't believe I didn't think about using absolute, that works perfectly - if you make it an answer I will accept it! Thanks

Comment: @Ben Holness it always happens :-). you are looking for a screw driver everywhere which is just in your hands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use absolute `position` property for navigation button for mobile. like `@media (max-width: 767px) {   .nav-prev{     position:absolute;     bottom:0;     left:0;   }   .nav-next{     position:absolute;     bottom:0;     right:0;   } }`

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment:

You can use `display: grid;` in mobile version. (use `@media` queries)

**NOTE THAT** `text-align: center;` and `border` I added **JUST** for demonstration purposes.

```css
.outer {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.content { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; border: 1px solid #767676;}
.nav-prev { grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2; border: 1px solid #767676;}
.nav-next { grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3; border: 1px solid #767676;}
```

```html
 <div class="outer">
<div class="nav-prev">PREV</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="nav-next">NEXT</div>
</div>
```

**IN CASE** If you want to use `display: grid;` in desktop version also. This will be your code for desktop:

```css
.outer {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: 1fr;
grid-column-gap: 0px;
grid-row-gap: 0px;
text-align: center;
}

.nav-prev { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2; border: 1px solid #767676;}
.content { grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3; border: 1px solid #767676;}
.nav-next { grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 4; border: 1px solid #767676;}
```

```html
 <div class="outer">
<div class="nav-prev">PREV</div>
<div class="content">CONTENT</div>
<div class="nav-next">NEXT</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked although there are some kinks that I would need to work out (spacing issues), however the absolute positioning idea is a much simpler solution. Thanks though!